# Apache Flink join streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to join two streams in Flink. The conditions are the following:

- Each one has a unique id to be used as the joining point.
- In both streams each key will only appear once.
- Keys in the streams will be separated at most 10 seconds.
- There is no event time but I can use both processing time or ingestion time. This restriction is important because doesn't let me use interval join that only works with event time.

What is the most simple/efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [exercise in the online Flink training](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares) that covers this case, so you can refer to that as a starting point.

The solution provided there implements this kind of one-to-one join, where each key occurs exactly once, as a `RichCoFlatMap`.

What's important in these situations is that you take care to never leak state -- which this implementation will do if for some keys one of the expected events never arrives, because the unmatched event will sit in state forever. Since you know that the events will never be more than 10 seconds apart, you can instead implement this as a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, and use a processing time timer to clear any state that would otherwise linger because of missing events. Or you could rely on [state TTL](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl) to clear any unused state.

Flink does support many kinds of join with its higher level APIs -- windowed joins, interval joins, temporal joins, etc -- but for this specific kind of join, none of those is a great match, and a low-level implementation with a process function is straightforward to implement and will perform very well.

Update:

You could implement this with count windows, with a count of two. But then if any events were missing you would have dangling windows lying around. This could be fixed with a custom Trigger that closes windows after a timeout.

Or you could implement this with session windows, by specifying a session gap larger than 10 seconds. However, the ProcessWindowFunction for a session window isn't called until after the gap has occurred, so the join results won't be produced until after waiting for the gap. Once again I think you could work around this with a custom Trigger.

Note that either of these window-based solutions depend on first merging the two streams together into one. You could use `union` for that, provided you arrange for both streams to have the same type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Reading Process Function documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html) I came across session windows as an alternative. In fact, the example provided in that documentation says "This simple example could have been implemented with session windows.". There will be any disadvantage of using it in my use case. I think the only drawback is that when the second key arrives it will wait for the timeout to delete the state.

Comment: I've extended my answer to address this.

Comment: Thanks. While not documented I have found that I can make interval join work with ingestion time. Isn't it the best solution as doesn't require any manual intervention about the triggers.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like a fine solution.

Comment: Link to exercise is broken. All examples I've found don't work. :( This is one of the main tasks why to use Flink, too hard to get started ..

Comment: @kev I've fixed the broken links.